# How to count rows that have the same values in two columns (SQL)?

Tags: sql

I am sure there must be a relatively straightforward way to do this, but it is escaping me at the moment.  Suppose I have a SQL table like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |
+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+
|  1  |  2  |  3  | foo | bar | << 1,2
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  3  |  3  | biz | bar | << 1,3
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  4  |  x  |  y  | << 1,2
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  5  | foo | bar | << 1,2
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  4  |  2  |  3  | foo | bar | << 4,2
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  3  |  3  | foo | bar | << 1,3
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Now, I want to know how many times each combination of values for columns A and B appear, regardless of the other columns.  So, in this example, I want an output something like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  |count|
+=====+=====+=====+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  3  |  2  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  4  |  2  |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

What would be the SQL to determine that?  I feel like this must not be a very uncommon thing to want to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
SELECT A,B,COUNT(*)
FROM the-table
GROUP BY A,B
```

Answer (score 15):

TRY:

```
SELECT
    A, B , COUNT(*)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY A, B
```

Answer (score 11):

This should do it:

```
SELECT A, B, COUNT(*) 
FROM TableName
GROUP BY A, B;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT A,B,COUNT(1) As COUNT_OF
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY A,B
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT A,B,COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY A,B
```

Answer (score 5):

SELECT A, B, COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY A, B

Answer (score 5):

This could be the answer:

```
SELECT a, b, COUNT(*) 
FROM <your table name here> 
GROUP BY a,b 
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

Comment: Also correct, but ordering by ordinals isn't a good habit iirc.

Comment: I thought I'd be the first to answer T_T.

Comment: @rexem I suppose you say it because of readability, I can't find other reason.

Comment: @snahor: It's because the ordinal is associated with the position in the SELECT.  If it moves, your ordering changes.