# How to count rows that have the same values in two columns and return only rows where count<N(SQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

regarding that question:
[How to count rows that have the same values in two columns (SQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597055/how-to-count-rows-that-have-the-same-values-in-two-columns-sql)

is there a way to return only the rows where the count is < 3?

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  |count|
+=====+=====+=====+
|  1  |  3  |  2  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  4  |  2  |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause

```
 SELECT ...
 FROM ...
 WHERE ...
 GROUP BY whatever
 HAVING count(*) <3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the condition in the `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT colName, COUNT(*)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY colName
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
```